# Alphametic-like fraction equaling 1/2; uniqueness of solutions

Tags: recreational-mathematics

This problem is kind of like those alphametics puzzles. The challenge is to assign each whole number from 2 to 9 to the letters in $$\frac{10^3A+10^2B+10C+D}{10^4+10^3E+10^2F+10G+H}$$ such that the fraction equals $\frac{1}{2}$.

(The original challenge was to simply have some ordering of the numbers 1 to 9 in a fraction, such that all the numbers were used exactly once, and the resulting fraction equaled 1/2, but the only possible solution is through this "structure" of $\frac{ABCD}{1EFGH}$.)

Using equal parts logic and bruteforcing, I got a solution of $6792/13584$. Is this a unique solution, and is there some sort of system (besides arbitrary deductions, with trial and error to fill in the gaps) that could give all answers for this sort of problem, or discern if there are none?

The obvious initial deductions: $$\begin{align*}A &\in \{6,7,8,9\}\\D &\in \{2,3,4,6,7,8,9\}\\E &\in \{2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}\\H &\in \{2,4,6,8\}\end{align*}$$

*Update:* I went and wrote up a quick program to bruteforce it, and there are 12 solutions: $$\begin{align*}\frac{1}{2}&=\frac{6729}{13458}=\frac{6792}{13584}=\frac{6927}{13854}=\frac{7269}{14538}=\frac{7293}{14586}=\frac{7329}{14658}\\\\&=\frac{7692}{15384}=\frac{7923}{15846}=\frac{7932}{15864}=\frac{9267}{18534}=\frac{9273}{18546}=\frac{9327}{18654}\end{align*}$$ This confirms the answer to the first question, but the proof for the second is still open. The initial deductions are reduced to the following, after looking at the answers: $$\begin{align*}A &\in \{6,7,9\}\\B,C &\in \{2,3,6,7,9\}\\D &\in \{2,3,7,9\}\\E &\in \{3,4,5,8\}\\F,G &\in \{3,4,5,6,8\}\\H &\in \{4,6,8\}\end{align*}$$ The numbers, once set, seem to interchange in interesting ways. There are two distinct groups of possible digits on the top, $\{2,3,7,9\}$ and $\{2,6,7,9\}$. Separating by the first digit, there are five groups. The proof would probably be based on making some of these logical reductions first, especially to $A$, $D$, $E$, and $H$. Maybe it would also incorporate a method of trying out coordinated switches? The way that $6729/13458$ and $6792/13584$ interchange seems to make that unlikely, but proofs tend to make more sense in hindsight anyway.

Comment: How about pure brute force: For every four-digit number $n$, check whether $n$ and $2n$ together has one of each digit among them? 10,000 steps does not seem bad.

Comment: `pastebay.com` seems shady. It only shows ads and malware. In Python, all the code you need is `['%d/%d' % (x, 2 * x) for x in range(10000) if set(str(x) + str(2 * x)) == set('123456789')]` to get `['6729/13458', '6792/13584', '6927/13854', '7269/14538', '7293/14586', '7329/14658', '7692/15384', '7923/15846', '7932/15864', '9267/18534', '9273/18546', '9327/18654']`.

Comment: @EricDuminil I asked this question six years ago, back when it wasn't shady and when I thought I had to prove I wrote the code. Thanks for noticing, I've removed the link.

Comment: @algorithmshark: I have no idea how I landed here, and didn't notice the question is from 2011. :) It might have been in "Related questions".

Comment: BTW, did you find any answer to the second question?

Comment: @EricDuminil If you mean, whether or not there exists an intelligent way of enumerating the solutions to alphametics like this, then no, I haven't the foggiest.

Answer (score 2):

According to my alphametic solver http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/applet/metic/metic.html the solutions of the alphametic ABCD + ABCD = QEFGH are

8532+8532=17064
7932+7932=15864
8352+8352=16704
9352+9352=18704
8652+8652=17304
6852+6852=13704
5382+5382=10764
5392+5392=10784
7692+7692=15384
6792+6792=13584
8523+8523=17046
7923+7923=15846
9273+9273=18546
7293+7293=14586
6354+6354=12708
5364+5364=10728
8235+8235=16470
9235+9235=18470
6435+6435=12870
8645+8645=17290
6485+6485=12970
5436+5436=10872
8546+8546=17092
5486+5486=10972
9327+9327=18654
6927+6927=13854
9267+9267=18534
5238+5238=10476
7329+7329=14658
6729+6729=13458
5239+5239=10478
7269+7269=14538

Now discard those that have contain 0.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer part of the question: you haven't found the only solution. $${9327\over18654}={1\over2}$$ also works. I don't know if there are more. The only methods I know are educated trial and error, and Henning's method from the comments.